# Why does declaring this variable globally cause a segfault?

Tags: android, c++, x86, segmentation-fault

Let's compare two versions of a unit test I have:

```
const VersionVector kTestVers {"2@*,3@$,1@bob"_sl}; // Adding 'static' does not help
const VersionVector kTestCASVers {"3@$,2@*"_sl};

static void a() {
   // verify something with these two things
}

static void b() {
   // create something with these two things
}
```

and

```
static void a() {
   const VersionVector kTestVers {"2@*,3@$,1@bob"_sl};
   const VersionVector kTestCASVers {"3@$,2@*"_sl};
   // verify something with these two things
}

static void b() {
   const VersionVector kTestVers {"2@*,3@$,1@bob"_sl};
   const VersionVector kTestCASVers {"3@$,2@*"_sl};
   // create something with these two things
}
```

I was working with this on my Nexus 5 (armeabi-v7a), and decided to see how it would fare in a Genymotion VM (x86).  Both of these work fine on the device, but on the VM the first version immediately segfaults while the second version works.  The stack trace of the segfault shows that the fault happened during the initialization of the global variables:

> #00 pc 00114e7f  /data/local/tmp/LiteCore/CppTests (litecore::VersionVector::VersionVector(fleece::slice)+207)
>    #01 pc 00010b48  /data/local/tmp/LiteCore/CppTests (_GLOBAL__sub_I_RevisionTest.cc+104)
>    #02 pc 00003203  /system/bin/linker (__dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv.part.140+1055)
>    #03 pc 0000ddbe  /system/bin/linker (__dl___linker_init+4558)
>    #04 pc 00010c17  /system/bin/linker (__dl__start+29)
>    #05 pc 00000001  < unknown >

`VersionVector` has three member variables, one of which is `std::vector<Version>`.  The offending line causing the segfault is a `push_back` on that vector of a `Version` object constructed as part of the constructor:

```
VersionVector::VersionVector(slice string)
:_string(string)
{
    if (string.size == 0 || string.findByte('\0'))
        error::_throw(error::BadVersionVector);

    while (string.size > 0) {
        const void *comma = string.findByte(',');
        if (comma == nullptr) {
            comma = string.end();
        }
        _vers.push_back( Version(string.upTo(comma), false) ); // This line causes the segfault, and constructing the object separately does not help
        string = string.from(comma);
        if (string.size > 0)
            string.moveStart(1); // skip comma
    }
}
```

Is there some undefined behavior in here mucking things up?

**EDIT**: Additional defs

```
class Version {
public:
    // Methods and one static const size_t...
private:
    friend class VersionVector;
    peerID      _author; //peerID is typedef'd to slice
    generation  _gen {0};  //generation is typedef'd to uint64_t
}

struct slice {
    const void* buf;
    size_t size;

    // Methods...
}
```

Also this entire repo is on Github.  [Here](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-core/blob/cbe1454e20746f506e5ca133f62410ddb39d40ff/LiteCore/tests/RevisionTest.cc) is the file with the unit tests, the file [with VersionVector and Version](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-core/blob/cbe1454e20746f506e5ca133f62410ddb39d40ff/LiteCore/VersionVectors/VersionVector.hh) and the file [with slice](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/fleece/blob/eeace231bc5667791706c92658ddca1ec7a401d1/Fleece/slice.hh)

**EDIT** Some new info:

The presence of the `_author` field on `Version` affects this.  In the simplest form I can think of I have boiled it down to just this:

```
#include "VersionVector.hh"
#include "slice.hh"
using namespace fleece;
using namespace litecore;

const VersionVector kTestVers {"2@*,3@$,1@bob"_sl};
const VersionVector kTestCASVers {"3@$,2@*"_sl};

int main()
{
}
```

This causes a segfault too.  I commented out everything except the stuff that is involved above, and only compiled the Fleece static lib (which has `slice`) and VersionVector.cc, along with the above `main.cpp`.  If I comment out the `_author` field then no more segfault, and even if I don't assign it to anything and just leave it in the class I get the segfault.

Comment: It may be due to undefined order of initialization of global variables. Does `VersionVector` depend (maybe indirectly, say, through the `slice` or `Version` types) on another global object?

Comment: Are you sure you want `void*` in c++, Can you show us your `Version` and string?

Comment: @Danh What `void*`?  I added the `Version` and `slice` defs, but the code doesn't pass through there on the actual stack trace.  It is inside the `push_back` that the badness happens.

Comment: `const void *comma = string.findByte(',');` And, with your rep, I think you should know how to create an MVCE. It's hard to tell anything from your code

Comment: After looking around your code in GitHub, line 56 and 59 in slide.hh is not good to me. Anyway, I can't find any reason to stand for using `void*`

Comment: @Danh Thanks for your analysis!  I will keep it in mind.

Comment: You should break that line down into 3 lines (doing the upto, doing the Version constructor, doing the push back) to see which part is broken.  As is, we don't have enough code to solve it.

Comment: I did that already, as noted in my comment.  The `push_back` alone is the problem.  I am getting closer to some other related info though.

Comment: @Leon You might be onto something, as I point out in my edit that I just made.

Comment: @Danh: Could you tell us what you think is wrong at those two lines in slice.hh (the constructor from `string` and the deleted `operator=` from `alloc_slice`)?

Comment: Since this crash only occurs in one particular emulator, not on any of the other platforms we've run this code on, I'm suspecting it's a bug in the emulator. Or maybe in Android x86 codegen. And it sounds like it's happening when a `slice` gets copied as part of the vector append, so maybe adding an explicit copy ctor to `slice` would help...